# Dedekind-esque sums

Tags: nt.number-theory

Given real numbers $a, b$, let $f(x)$ be the integer nearest to $ax+b$,
let $S_n$ be $\sum_{k=0}^{n} (n-2k) f(n-k) =
n f(n) + (n-2) f(n-1) + (n-4) f(n-2) + ... - (n-2) f(1) - n f(0)$,
and let $s_n = an(n+1)(n+2)/6$ (the value you would get if you replaced 
each term $f(x)$ in the sum by the associated $x$).  I believe (with no 
especially good evidence) that for a set of real numbers $a$ of full measure,
and for all real numbers $b$, $|S_n - s_n|$ is $O(n)$.  Is this true?

This is an updated version of the question "sums involving the nearest-integer function" that I posted a couple of weeks ago.  One person who replied to that
post appeared to be claiming that if $a$ is any irrational number and $b = 0$ then $|(S_n - s_n)/n|$ is unbounded.  Can anyone provide a proof, or steer me
towards a proof in the on-line literature?  (I tried $a = (1+\sqrt{5})/2$ and 
$b = 0$, and I found that $\max_{n \leq N} |(S_n - s_n)/n|$ takes on the successive values 0.59, 0.81, 0.81, and 1.10 for $N = 10,10^2,10^3,$ and $10^4$.)

When $a$ is rational, it is easy to show that $|S_n - s_n|$ is $O(n)$.  In 
this case, are there good bounds of the form $Cn$ for explicit constants $C$ 
(presumably obtained from the continued fraction expansion of $a$)?

Comment: What happens if you rewrite $f(x)$ as $[ax+b+(1/2)]$, which is $ax+b+(1/2)-\{ax+b+(1/2)\}$? You get a main term and then a term involving a sum with fractional parts, which may be in the literature. 

Comment: Further to my comment, you get $S_n-s_n=-\sum_{r=0}^n(2r-n)\{ar+b'\}$ where $b'=b+(1/2)$. I suspect this is in the discrepancy literature. 

Comment: You may find what you need among the answers at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17132/bounds-on-sum-n-alpha-n-where-x-is-the-sawtooth-function